# How do I present a camera in front of a UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

iOS 10.3.1

After my UINavigationController is presented with one pushed view controller, I have the following view hierarchy (excerpt from top... not full depth)

```
(lldb) po [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] firstObject] recursiveDescription]
<UIWindow: 0x15592120; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x15592b80>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x155923b0>>
   | <UITransitionView: 0x1840d0e0; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x1732a4d0>>
   |    | <UILayoutContainerView: 0x1749a730; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x16ec4900>; layer = <CALayer: 0x18509620>>
   |    |    | <UINavigationTransitionView: 0x17498d40; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x16e731b0>>
   |    |    |    | <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0x185a5820; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x16ae0f40>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x173f83c0; frame = (0 64; 768 960); autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 500; layer = <CALayer: 0x171775c0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x16fda3b0; frame = (0 0; 768 35); autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 502; layer = <CALayer: 0x1681afa0>>
```

How do I present a camera in front of this from code located in my AppDelegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was mentioned in a comment by @stevenpcurtis.
Instead of presenting the `UINavigationController`, I added it to a parent container view like this...

```
-(void)addAChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childViewController
    {
        [self addChildViewController:childViewController];
        [self.view addSubview:childViewController.view];
        [childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    }
```

And instead of dismissing the `UINavigationController`, I just remove it with code like this...

```
-(void)removeThisViewControllerFromItsParent
    {
        [self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self removeFromParentViewController];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add views to the Window

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
window.addSubview((popupReference.view)!)
```

So will appear in front of everything

Comment: I'm going to try that, but I don't need just a subview, like adding a label or text control... don't I need to add the camera's view controller to the controller's hierarchy as well?

Comment: Use a containerview and add it all into that? Or pass the stream (if video) or image (if picture) into a UIView.

Comment: stevenpcurtis - You're worth your weight in bitcoin.  -->"Use a containerview and add it all into that"  that WORKED !!!   If you post as an answer instead of a comment, I can give you credit for it

Answer (score 0):

You can add a view to the window

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
window.addSubview((yourView)!)
```

where yourView can be a Container (containers are just UIViews in any case) which can then be added to the window using the code above